# Filename wildcard expansion in GRUB scripting

Tags: scripting, grub, grub2

Is it filename wildcard expansion possible in GRUB scripts?

Something like:

```
for i in directory/*; do echo $i; done
```

My intention is for GRUB to load different cfg files located in certain directories.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible if you have the `regexp` module, which seems to use the same syntax for filename expansion as bash. I discovered this accidentally and I still am not sure if there is any mention of this feature in the documentation. Example:

```
insmod regexp
for i in /opt/*; do echo $i; done
```

I entered this into GRUB 2.02 shell on my system and received this output:

```
/opt/sublime_text
/opt/google
```